# ARMA(1,2)-EGARCH(2,1) leverage interpretation in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am starting with statistics and I am facing an issue with an ARMA-eGARCH model.

Im having an issue with the interpretation of the gamma coefficient from the fit of ARMA(1,2)-eGARCH(2,1) using the rugarch package.

As I know the gamma parameter is the leverage and when gamma is negative it means that the model has leverage effect, but the problem is here in this model I have two gamma parameters and one is negative but the other is positive.

How can I interpret this case?

Here is the model fit.

Thanks for your help!

```
*---------------------------------*
*          GARCH Model Fit        *
*---------------------------------*

Conditional Variance Dynamics   
-----------------------------------
GARCH Model : eGARCH(2,1)
Mean Model  : ARFIMA(1,0,2)
Distribution    : std 

Optimal Parameters
------------------------------------
        Estimate  Std. Error     t value Pr(>|t|)
mu      0.002335    0.000586  3.9845e+00 0.000068
ar1     0.984861    0.004176  2.3583e+02 0.000000
ma1    -1.039860    0.000004 -2.6259e+05 0.000000
ma2     0.062858    0.002236  2.8106e+01 0.000000
omega  -0.027390    0.009831 -2.7860e+00 0.005336
alpha1 -0.036038    0.048493 -7.4316e-01 0.457383
alpha2  0.092501    0.048862  1.8931e+00 0.058344
beta1   0.995196    0.001996  4.9852e+02 0.000000
gamma1  0.345047    0.061117  5.6457e+00 0.000000
gamma2 -0.093125    0.058722 -1.5859e+00 0.112770
shape   2.533085    0.146629  1.7276e+01 0.000000

Robust Standard Errors:
        Estimate  Std. Error     t value Pr(>|t|)
mu      0.002335    0.000570  4.1000e+00 0.000041
ar1     0.984861    0.004516  2.1809e+02 0.000000
ma1    -1.039860    0.000003 -4.0642e+05 0.000000
ma2     0.062858    0.002186  2.8754e+01 0.000000
omega  -0.027390    0.015389 -1.7799e+00 0.075091
alpha1 -0.036038    0.048691 -7.4014e-01 0.459217
alpha2  0.092501    0.047530  1.9462e+00 0.051636
beta1   0.995196    0.002408  4.1322e+02 0.000000
gamma1  0.345047    0.058689  5.8792e+00 0.000000
gamma2 -0.093125    0.057076 -1.6316e+00 0.102767
shape   2.533085    0.150352  1.6848e+01 0.000000

LogLikelihood : 5007.332 

Information Criteria
------------------------------------
                
Akaike       -4.1004
Bayes        -4.0742
Shibata      -4.1004
Hannan-Quinn -4.0909

Weighted Ljung-Box Test on Standardized Residuals
------------------------------------
                         statistic   p-value
Lag[1]                       13.66 2.196e-04
Lag[2*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][8]      21.16 0.000e+00
Lag[4*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][14]     27.59 7.616e-10
d.o.f=3
H0 : No serial correlation

Weighted Ljung-Box Test on Standardized Squared Residuals
------------------------------------
                         statistic p-value
Lag[1]                     0.01507  0.9023
Lag[2*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][8]    3.28506  0.6332
Lag[4*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][14]   4.72452  0.8028
d.o.f=3

Weighted ARCH LM Tests
------------------------------------
            Statistic Shape Scale P-Value
ARCH Lag[4]    0.2978 0.500 2.000  0.5853
ARCH Lag[6]    4.7944 1.461 1.711  0.1259
ARCH Lag[8]    5.0893 2.368 1.583  0.2395

Nyblom stability test
------------------------------------
Joint Statistic:  4.1596
Individual Statistics:              
mu     0.16397
ar1    0.07774
ma1    0.06603
ma2    0.05386
omega  0.57411
alpha1 1.27031
alpha2 1.05386
beta1  0.56587
gamma1 0.73976
gamma2 0.33343
shape  0.15746

Asymptotic Critical Values (10% 5% 1%)
Joint Statistic:         2.49 2.75 3.27
Individual Statistic:    0.35 0.47 0.75

Sign Bias Test
------------------------------------
                   t-value   prob sig
Sign Bias           0.9524 0.3410    
Negative Sign Bias  1.4660 0.1428    
Positive Sign Bias  0.6865 0.4925    
Joint Effect        3.3397 0.3422    


Adjusted Pearson Goodness-of-Fit Test:
------------------------------------
  group statistic p-value(g-1)
1    20     24.02       0.1955
2    30     33.45       0.2599
3    40     45.94       0.2067
4    50     51.08       0.3919


Elapsed time : 0.820385
```

Comment: If you are asking on how to interpret the results of your statistical analysis, you might be better off asking over at [Cross Validated](stats.stackexchange.com/), as stackoverflow is for programming related questions

Comment: @Jonathan Ive been answered by my teacher, but that is a good point, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been answered by the master's teacher, he said that gamma2 is very small compared to gamma1 and gamma2 is very close to zero too. So we can neglect that value.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).